# How to override top menu css in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, theme, css

I want to **override top menu CSS** and replace it with **my own CSS**.

> I don't know which CSS file is responsible to display top menu.
>   I only need to override CSS and don't want to make any changes to the top menu.

Comment: Your top menu is an extension or in theme  ?

Comment: default menu provided by magento @PЯINCƏ

Comment: ok, which theme are you using

Comment: @PЯINCƏ magento luma with sample data

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I see is to add some `new class` in topmenu then you customise your css as you need.

The class name that I added is : `topmenu-v2`

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{yourthemename}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml

```
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>

<nav class="navigation topmenu-v2" data-action="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_menu ?>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

then :

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{yourthemename}/web/css/yourcssname.css

```
//example:

.navigation.topmenu-v2 {
    background: #878787;
}

.navigation.topmenu-v2 ul{
    ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: This  css is  to display menu vertically or you have just given for example ??

Comment: if you have any css that will work to display menu vertically it will be great because i am new to magento and not having that much knowledge about frontend css

Comment: Look my edit, the native luma menu, I hanven't that css for vertical one

Comment: if you have any tutorial link for vertical css then it will also  very helpful to me

Comment: should i call that css in my themes  layout folders   default.xml file ??

Comment: you have to declare it in `default_head_blocks.xml`